# Dropdown filter by product

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My dedicated filter dropdown is not filtering some of the products in my list of products. For example, the two options display if I select Phones in the category and select Samsung. But if I select watch Apple Watch, nothing displays. How do I ensure something is displayed when I select them in the category and subcategory as long as they are in the google sheets? I have added images.

Here is the code

```
    function getCategories() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Product");
  var categories = [];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var category = data[i][0];
    if (categories.indexOf(category) == -1) {
      categories.push(category);
    }
  }
  return categories;
}

function getSubCategories(category) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Product");
  var subCategories = [];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowCategory = data[i][0];
    var subCategory = data[i][1];
    if (rowCategory == category && subCategories.indexOf(subCategory) == -1) {
      subCategories.push(subCategory);
    }
  }
  return subCategories;
}


function filterProducts(category, subCategory) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Product");
  var [headers, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var filteredData = data.filter(function (row) {
    return row[0] == category && row[1] == subCategory;
  });
  return [headers, ...filteredData];
}

function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  template.categories = getCategories();
  template.category = '';
  template.subCategory='';
  return template.evaluate().setTitle('Product Filter');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function getSheetData()  { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Product'); 
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();  
  return dataValues;
}


function getUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}
```

This is the script and html code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function getSubCategories(category) 
    {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    subCategory.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    subCategory.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      subCategory.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getSubCategories(category);
    
    };

      function updateSubCategories() {
        var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(subCategories) {
          var subCategoryDropdown = document.getElementById('sub-category');
          subCategoryDropdown.innerHTML = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < subCategories.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = subCategories[i];
            option.text = subCategories[i];
            subCategoryDropdown.appendChild(option);
          }
        }).getSubCategories(category);
      }
     
function filterProducts() {
  var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
  var subCategory = document.getElementById('sub-category').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(filteredData) {
    var [headers, ...filteredData] = filteredData;
    var productTable = document.getElementById('product-table');
    productTable.innerHTML = '';
    var headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      var headerCell = document.createElement('th');
      headerCell.textContent = headers[i];
      headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
    }
    productTable.appendChild(headerRow);
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
      var row = filteredData[i];
      var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
      for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) { 
        var tableCell = document.createElement('td');
        tableCell.textContent = row[j];
        tableRow.appendChild(tableCell);
      }
      productTable.appendChild(tableRow);
    }
  }).filterProducts(category, subCategory);
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Product Filter</h1>
    <?var tableData = getSheetData();?>
    <?var url = getUrl();?>
    <label for="category">Category:</label>
    <select id="category" onchange="updateSubCategories()">
      <? for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= categories[i] ?>"><?= categories[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
    </select>
    <label for="sub-category">Sub-Category:</label>
    <select id="sub-category" onchange="filterProducts()">
    </select><br><br>

    <? if(category != '' || subCategory != '')
    {
        var output_array = [];
        tableData.forEach(function(value, index) {
        
          if(index == 0)
          {
            output_array.push(value);
          }
          else if(index > 0 && category != '' && subCategory != '')
          {
            if(value[0] == category && value[2] == subCategory)
            {
              output_array.push(value);
             }
            }
            else if(index > 0 && category != '')
            {
              if(value[0] == category)
              {                       
                output_array.push(value);
              }            
            }
            else if(index > 0 && subCategory != '')
            {
              if(value[2] == subCategory)
              {                       
                output_array.push(value);
              }           
            }                           
        });
    }
    else
    {
      var output_array = tableData;    
    }  ?>
    <!-- <table id="product-table">

    </table> -->

    <table id="product-table" border="1" cellpadding="5px" >
    <?for(var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) { ?>
      <?if(i == 0) { ?>
        <tr>
        <?for(var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <th><?= tableData[i][j] ?></th>
        <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } else { ?>
        <tr>
        <? for(var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
          <td><?= tableData[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the image with the list of all the products

[image]

Here is the product after i filter for dell computer
[image]

This is the filter for watch.
[image]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: The problem is if I have data in more than five columns, it does not display that filter. So, for example, I have Category, Subcategory, price, discount, new price, and comment. If there is any category that has data in all of those fields, it will not display that row.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The problem is if I have data in more than five columns, it does not display that filter. So, for example, I have Category, Subcategory, price, discount, new price, and comment. If there is any category that has data in all of those fields, it will not display that row.`, in your showing script, there are 4 columns. So, I cannot understand your reply. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your actual question?

Comment: I have updated the pictures. If there is any information in the 6, 7, or 8 columns, the filter does not work. It only filters if the information is only in columns 1 through 5.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, when I saw your updated question, I was surprised that you had changed from your initial situation. In this case, first, can I ask you whether my proposed answer was useful for your initial situation? Because my answer is for your initial question.

Comment: Yes, that did help. I added the code. It's just that the filter is still not working.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your new question, I would like to support you. But, I think that when you provide more information, it will help think of the reason for your current issue and a solution. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, about `It's just that the filter is still not working.`, in this case, which filter is 1st dropdown list or 2nd dropdown list?

Comment: The first and second dropdown lists are populating. It is just not updating the table

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The first and second dropdown lists are populating. It is just not updating the table`, in this case, when you test your initial situation (5 columns), no issue occurs. And, when you change the number of columns from 5 to 8, this issue occurred. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, from your showing new Spreadsheet, I'm worried that your Spreadsheet includes the date object. If my understanding is correct, an error occurs when the values are sent from Google Apps Script to Javascript because of the current specification. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, please replace all `getValues()` with `getDisplayValues()` in your Google Apps Script side and reflect the latest script to Web Apps and test it again. By this, your new issue might be able to be removed. First, please test this.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. When I changed from 5 to 8 columns, the issue occurred.

Comment: By changing from getValues() to getDisplayValues(), it worked. thank you so much for all your help

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your 2nd issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about adding the initial value to 2nd dropdown list?
When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

Please modify `updateSubCategories()` of Javascript as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function updateSubCategories() {
  var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (subCategories) {
    var subCategoryDropdown = document.getElementById('sub-category');
    subCategoryDropdown.innerHTML = '';
    
    // --- I added the below script.
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "Please select";
    option.hidden = true;
    subCategoryDropdown.appendChild(option);
    // ---
    
    for (var i = 0; i < subCategories.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = subCategories[i];
      option.text = subCategories[i];
      subCategoryDropdown.appendChild(option);
    }
  }).getSubCategories(category);
}
```

- By this modification, when the values are set to the 2nd dropdown, the initial value is "Please select". I guessed that this might be your expected result.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".